# Functional Analysis Problem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let Y be a subspace of normed space X.
Show that if exists $a \in X, a \notin \overline Y$ then $f \in X'$ exists such that:

1) $ f\equiv0 $ on Y

2) $f(a)=d(a,Y)=inf_{y \in Y}||a-y||>0$

3) $||f||_{x'}=1$

$X'$ is the dual space and $\overline X$ is its closure

================================================================

I was thinking at this:

- let $0<d=d(a,Y)$
- z=span(Y,a)
- I define the next linear application on z: $f(y+ta)=td,\,y \in Y,\,t\in k$
- $f|_y=0$
- f(a)=d
- $u:=y+at,\,y \in Y,\, t scalar, u\neq0:$

$|f(u)|=|t|d=\frac{|t|*||u||}{||u||}d=\frac{|t|*||u||}{||y+ta||}d=\frac{||u||}{||\frac{y}{t}+a||}d=\frac{||u||d}{a-(-\frac{y}{t})||} \le \frac{||u||d}{d(a,Y)}=||u||$

=> $||f|| \le 1$

- $\exists (Yn)n \, such\, that\, ||Yn-a|| \rightarrow d$
- $d=|f(Yn)-f(a)| \le ||f||*||Yn-a||$

  when $n \rightarrow \infty:$

  $d \le ||f||d$

=> ||f||=1, f(a)=d(a,Y)

- I extend on X with the same norm

Comment: You probably mean $a \notin \overline{Y}$ and not $a \notin \overline{X}$. This is then an application of the Hahn Banach theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the mistake I made

Comment: Please, can you tell me which version of the Hahn Banach Theorem I should use?

Comment: there is only one version of the Hahn Banach theorem..

Comment: can you start by writing what means $\|f\|_{X'}$ ? (hence what is $X'$)

Comment: thank you for your help! I managed to do something. I will put it here tomorrow.